# In Facebook api how to set the limit for Feeds to get next 5 feeds?

Tags: ios, facebook

I am using the following code to get the feeds:

```
NSDictionary *dirTemp;

NSError *error;

NSStringEncoding encoding;

NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/posts?access_token=AppID|AppSecret&limit=5",strIdValue];
//NSLog(@"Your String URL is %@",strUrl);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[strUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *strResonse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];

dirTemp = [strResonse JSONValue];
```

Comment: You should not post your secret values. Also, your end point seems to be correct, what problem are you facing?

Comment: I got the solution in the response.In response it contain one pagination link for next 5 Facebook feeds.

Comment: It would be nice if you could add the same as answer and accept it to help people in future facing similar issue.

Comment: NSDictionary *dirTemp;
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/posts?access_token=AppID|AppSecret&limit=5",strIdValue];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[strUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *strResonse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];

dirTemp = [strResonse JSONValue];NSDictionary *paginationDict=[dirTemp valueForKey:@"paging"];
  NSString *pagelink=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[paginationDict objectForKey:@"next"]];

Comment: Add it in answers below, and accept it. Not in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *dirTemp;

NSStringEncoding encoding;

NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"graph.facebook.com/%@/…;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[strUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

NSString *strResonse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
dirTemp = [strResonse JSONValue];
NSDictionary *paginationDict=[dirTemp valueForKey:@"paging"];
NSString *pagelink=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[paginationDict objectForKey:@"next"]];
```